# How many verticies to be removed to transform from $Q_{10}$ to spanning tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I got that in $Q_2$ it is a square with 1 circuit. So by removing one vertex we produce a spanning tree (a line with length of 3)

So in $Q_3$ I tried again. I got that if I removed 3 vertices to produce a spanning tree. (I got a line with length of 5)

So my hypothesis is $Q_4$ will need to remove $16-7 = 9$ vertices. But this is not the case. When I tried, I only need to remove 7 vertices to produce a panning tree (As in the image below)

So I am out of ideas. Is there are theorems state about removing vertices that will help me solve this problem?

**Update image**

Apparently I cut one vertex too many

[$Q_4$ new result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siSna.png)

Comment: From your picture of $Q_4$ I get the idea that $Q_n$ is the edge graph of an $n$-dimensional cube. Now a spanning tree is not obtained by removing vertices but by removing edges.

Comment: I get that to get spanning tree from any graph $G = (V, E)$. The amount of edge to be removed is $|E| - |V| + 1$ edges. But the problem I got is to removed vertices. For example in $Q_3$ each vertex will have 3 edges. By removing that vertex. We also removed 3 edges.

Comment: @HelloIamnew: If you remove one vertex and its attached edges from $Q_2$, you get a chain of $3$ vertices and $2$ edges; this is *not* a spanning tree for $Q_2$, since it doesn’t even contain all of the vertices of $Q_2$. I’m not sure, because you’re misusing the terminology rather badly, but I *think* that you’re actually asking for the smallest number of vertices that can be removed to leave a tree — ***not*** a spanning tree. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think I had misused the word spanning tree wrong.